# Usecase docker node imaging labels

Tags: docker

I have docker file and see there is a constraint that's been applied using

node.labels.imaging == true

Can someone clarify how imaging constraint work?

I saw this link on nodes in a swarm but could find any description about imaging.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node.labels.imaging == true
```

In that example, imaging is the name of the label. Node labels are user defined, so you would need to define the "imaging" label yourself and set it to true on the nodes where you want the above constraint to be valid. You would do this with:

```
docker node update --label-add imaging=true $your_node_name
```